# Link from Jenkins Pipeline page to SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I've set up a multi-branch pipeline in Jenkins which performs a SonarQube analysis using the `withSonarQubeEnv()` step and the `sonar:sonar` Maven goal.

This works fine, and the analysis results do show up in SonarQube.

What I'm missing (compared to the traditional non-pipeline Jenkins integration) is a clickable link on the Jenkins build page which will open the analysis results in SonarQube.

There is a small SonarQube icon next to every build in the left panel, but this icon is not clickable.

Is there any configuration switch that will produce a clickable link, or is this simply a missing feature?

Comment: I think this non-clickable icon comes from the plugin which is run in normal job types. If you see that icon - maybe the location of sonarqube results are in different than usual place and the plugin doesn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Once the job is complete, the plugin will detect that a SonarQube analysis was made during the build and display a badge and a widget on the job page with a link to the SonarQube dashboard as well as quality gate status.

Please refer [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) and verify your configurations.

If this is happening to you, verify that the test is actually running if not, verify your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the SonarQube link on the build job page (for example `job/foo/1/`). However the link is on the project pate (that is `job/foo`). There you will find one link on the menu to the left and a `SonarQube Quality Gate widget in the bottom center`.

**Menu**

[image]

**Widget**

[image: widget]